# How do I sort lines semi-lexiographically in emacs -- i.e., lexiographically, except that 3 gets sorted above 11?

Tags: emacs

How do I sort lines semi-lexiographically in emacs -- i.e., lexiographically, except that  3 gets sorted above 11? For example, I have a large collection of data, each entry of which looks like

```
[ 5, 3, 21, 1600000 ],
[ 3, 11, 21, 6400000 ],
[ 3, 3, 102, 1600000 ],
```

etc...

M-x sort-lines sorts this as

```
[ 3, 11, 21, 6400000 ],
[ 3, 3, 102, 1600000 ],
[ 5, 3, 21, 1600000 ],
```

but I would really like this sorted as

```
[ 3, 3, 102, 1600000 ],
[ 3, 11, 21, 6400000 ],
[ 5, 3, 21, 1600000 ],
```

Thanks!

Comment: that's not strictly lexicographically for an editor. An editor handles text, and the sort that Emacs did by default _is_ proper lexicographical sort of strings

Comment: Thanks sehe, you are correct. I will edit the question.

Comment: Have you tried sort-numeric-fields?

Comment: hmmm yeah - that title is way more obvious now LOL

Answer (score 3):

sehe [gives a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461326/how-do-i-sort-lines-semi-lexiographically-in-emacs-i-e-lexiographically-exc#6461371). Here it is in Emacs:

```
C-u M-| sort -k2n -k3n
```

Run that with your region selected and it will be replaced with the `sort` ouput!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use emacs, but in vim I'd do:

```
%!sort -k2n -k3n
```

(possibly using the other key columns as well, I can't tell form the sample)

I'm not starting the editor war here... I'm just pretty sure that emacs allows you to filter through a shell command as well, so this will help!

Answer (score 2):

With your data, the following will do what you want, though it is a bit laborious:

```
C-u 3 M-x sort-numeric-fields
C-u 2 M-x sort-numeric-fields
```

I don't know for sure that `sort-numeric-fields` is a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability), so it may not always work.  And, obviously the above only sorts 2 numbers "deep" and you'll need to add <kbd>C-u 4 M-x sort...</kbd> if you want to sort by the 3rd number.  The prefix argument starts with 2 because the first field is the `[`, and counting begins with 1.

You could also roll your own by calling `sort-subr` with the appropriate, lexographic, predicate.  See the [documentation for sort-subr](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Sorting.html) for more details.